# maya api custom node,get plug in CompoundAttribute

Tags: c++, maya-api

I have written a custom MPXnode that is only used to store data,
in the Initialize() section of mpxnode:

```
    MFnCompoundAttribute compAttr;
    MFnNumericAttribute numericAttr;

    arrayCacheObj = numericAttr.create("doubleArrayC", "dAC", MFnNumericData::kDouble, 0.0);
    numericAttr.setStorable(true);
    numericAttr.setWritable(true);
    numericAttr.setKeyable(true);
    numericAttr.setReadable(true);
    numericAttr.setArray(true);

    arrayCacheCompObj = compAttr.create("doubleArray", "dA");
    compAttr.setArray(true);

    compAttr.addChild(arrayCacheObj);

    addAttribute(arrayCacheCompObj);
```

I try to get child plug in my mpxcommand and set value:

```
MFnDependencyNode arrayCacheNodeFn(arrayCacheNode)
MPlug dAPlug = arrayCacheNodeFn.findPlug("doubleArray", true);

dAPlug.elementByLogicalIndex(0).elementByLogicalIndex(0).setValue(2);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKc4b.png)
The command couldn't find the corresponding plug I thought, and I also tried the.child(0) method.What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who has this problem:
dAPlug.elementByLogicalIndex(0).child(0).elementByLogicalIndex(0).setValue(2);

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).